# How to select each option in dropdown list and click a button (same origin policy issue - permission denied on the second iteration)

Tags: excel, vba, web, web-scraping, automation

I need a code that loops through options in a < select > object on a web page, selects each option and clicks "Show" button to show some data related to the selected option. I started with this code:

```
Set periodSelector = ie.document.getElementById("period")
For Each Period In periodSelector.Options
    Period.Selected = True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(waittime))
Next Period
```

It works well - the browser selects each option just fine. But when I add button.click to show the data related to the selected option, an error "Permission denied" occurs on the second selector loop (seems like it cannot use .select command anymore).

```
Set periodSelector = ie.document.getElementById("period")
For Each Period In periodSelector.Options
    Period.Selected = True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(waittime))
    ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(17).Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(waittime))
Next Period
```

I guess it is due to same origin policy. Probably, when I click on the "Show" button, the page gets refreshed (although it is not really reloaded - the button uses scripts to retrieve some information and show it in a table below the button).
How can I avoid this same origin policy issue and loop through the dropdown options?

Comment: Can you share the url? There could be a number of things at play here.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible - login/password protected and contains classified information. If this helps: the page contains a table, a dropdown, and a button. When I manually select from the dropdown, nothing happens. But when I manually click the button "Show" the page reloads (the URL is still the same though, it is like the page just gets some data and reloads in order to show it) and the table updates with the retreived information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this I try a slightly different approach which is to work off the page and not a variable. You can get your number of options from an initial variable, but after that keep working off the current document which may have refreshed. Amongst other things, you want to avoid underlying stale element exceptions.

```
Dim periodSelector As Object, i As Long, optionsLength As Long
Set periodSelector = ie.document.querySelectorAll("#period option")
optionsLength = periodSelector.Length -1

For i = 0 to optionsLength
    ie.document.querySelectorAll("#period option").item(i).Selected = True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue(waittime)
    ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(17).Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue(waittime)  '<== this I would replace with proper page load wait      While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
Next
```